# Unable to Enter a Country

Tags: south-africa

If I have a connecting flight through a country I am unable to enter. Can I retrieve my bags to recheck for my connect?

Comment: There's no need to ask the same question twice.

Comment: Where are you travelling from/to and where are you transiting through? You've tagged the question south-africa, but that could be the answer to any of the three question, or it could be your nationality while you travel involves three different countries.

Answer (score 3):

> If I have a connecting flight through a country I am unable to enter. Can I retrieve my bags to recheck for my connect?

In general, the answer to this question is *no.*  In some cases, you may even be prohibited from transit without bags and without needing to clear immigration controls.

There may be exceptions to the general answer, but investigating all the possibilities would be prohibitively time consuming.  If you have a particular airport in mind, with a particular point of origin and destination, and a particular nationality of the traveler, please add them to the question.